# How would I plot points and make a line in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So Im supposed to plot graphs. Make a function plot_line(p1,p2) that takes two points as input arguments and plots the line between them. The two input arguments should be
lists or tuples specifying x- and y-coordinates, i.e., p1 =(x1,y1)

I tried with this but my graph is just empty in the plot table. Nothing comes up

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
print('this code will plot two points in a graph and make a line')

x1 = (float(input('enter first x value: ')))
y1 = (float(input('enter first y value: ')))
x2 = (float(input('enter second x value: ')))
y2 = (float(input('enter second y value: ')))


def plotline(p1,p2):
    p1=[x1,y1]
    p2=[x2,y2]
    
    return p1,p2


x=plotline(x1,x2)
y=plotline(x1,x2)

plt.plot(x,y, label='x,y')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.axis([-10,10,-10,10])
plt.title('two lines')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, i just run your code and get a nice line. Can you elaborate on your situation further?

Comment: im supposed to get one vertical and one horizontal line by doing x=0 and y=0 in the other, but it doesnt work.

Comment: im supposed to have two lines, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

**plt.plot()** takes three input to work

If you just write **plt.plot(3,4)**, it only pins the location but doesn't point it.

You need to write **plt.plot(3,4,'o').** this way you will pin and point the location with a **'o'** structure

Comment: what are you talking about?? no

Comment: Please be more precise. Describe the programming language you are using

Answer (score 1):

Complementing [Prateek Tripathi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196603/14184087) and according to what I understood. There are two things you need to fix in your code.

### Plotting

For more information on how to 'nicely' plot check [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

### Your implementation

Your function `plotline` it's acting weird and and I think it doesn't do what it should. Try with this one

```py
def plotLine(p1, p2):
    x = (p1[0], p2[0]) # Extracting x's values of points 
    y = (p1[1], p2[1]) # Extracting y's values of points
    plt.plot(x,y, '-o',label='x,y') # Plotting points
```

where `p1` and `p2` must be tuples of the coordinates corresponding to the points of your line. The tuples can be created manually by `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`; or with a function similar the next one

```py
def coordinates2tuple(x, y):
    return (x, y)
```

### At the end

your code could looks like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def coordinates2tuple(x, y):
    return (x, y)

def plotLine(p1, p2):
    x = (p1[0], p2[0]) # Extracting x's values of points 
    y = (p1[1], p2[1]) # Extracting y's values of points
    plt.plot(x,y, '-o',label='x,y') # Plotting points
    
    
    
print('this code will plot two points in a graph and make a line')

x1 = (float(input('enter first x value: ')))
y1 = (float(input('enter first y value: ')))
x2 = (float(input('enter second x value: ')))
y2 = (float(input('enter second y value: ')))



p1 = coordinates2tuple(x1, y1)
p2 = coordinates2tuple(x2, y2)

plotLine(p1, p2)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-10,10,-10,10])
plt.title('two lines')
plt.show()
```

That with the next execution

```
$ python3 trs.py 
this code will plot two points in a graph and make a line
enter first x value: 0
enter first y value: 0
enter second x value: 1
enter second y value: 1
```

shows
[image]

Comment: the p1 and p2 needs x1 and x2 from the input. its with user input so i input the x and y values for the coordinates of the points through the console.

Comment: what about the second line?

Comment: What do you mean by second line? If you only have two points you can only define one line.